# Cómo manejar los errores de sqlsrv

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

estoy intentando obtener los datos de una base de datos por medio de su clave primaria, en algunos casos es numérico pero en otro es alfanumérico, me funciona bien hasta que empiezan los datos alfanuméricos y de ahí ya no sirve, este es el código.

```
<?php 
        $var = $_POST['empresa'];
        //echo "<p> $var </p>";
        require("connect.php");
        $sql = "SELECT NOMBRE, TELEFONO, EMAILPRED FROM CLIE01 where CLAVE = $var";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $nombre = $row['NOMBRE'];
            $telefono = $row['TELEFONO'];
            $correo = $row['EMAILPRED'];
    ?>
    <div>
        <h3><?php echo $nombre; ?></h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Telefono: </b> <?php echo $telefono; ?><br>
                <b>Correo: </b> <?php echo $correo; ?><br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

El error que me genera es el siguiente sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya intentaste poniendole comillas simples a tu consulta?
$sql = "SELECT NOMBRE, TELEFONO, EMAILPRED FROM CLIE01 where CLAVE = '".$var."'";
te recomiendo usar pdo para que solo mandes las variables como parametros

Comment: ¿Cómo sería mediante el uso de PDO?